# Azure multistage pipelines: conditionally skip one stage but not the next

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, multistage-pipeline

I have an Azure multi-stage CI/CD pipeline. It has stages for Test and UAT deployment.

I want the UAT release to run if Test succeeds or is skipped, but not if it fails.

I can't.  Whatever I try, if Test is skipped, UAT is also skipped.  Unless I use `always()`, but then UAT will run even if Test fails.

```
  ...
  - stage: Test
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['build.sourceBranchName'], 'DoUAT')) # Skip for UAT deployment tests
    ...

  - stage: UAT
    condition: and(succeeded(), in(variables['build.sourceBranchName'], 'master', 'DoUAT')) # Only deploy off master branch and branch to test UAT deploys.
    ...
```

How do I skip one stage but not the next one?

[image: What I get vs what I want]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `not(failed('Test'))` condition, please try below condition.

```
- stage: UAT
    condition: and(not(failed('Test')), in(variables['build.sourceBranchName'], 'master', DoUAT')) # Only deploy off master branch and branch to test UAT deploys.
    ...
```

I tested and it worked, check below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks; looks like that is doing what I want.

Answer (score 18):

Credit to https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7738#issuecomment-611815486

@EdH

```yaml
condition: not(or(failed(), canceled()))
```

Works with multiple previous stages and works like you need. Run the stage if all previous stages are `succeeded` or `skipped`, but not if they are `failed` or `cancelled`.

[image]

Notes:

- Skipping does not cause failed() or cancelled() to be true.
- Skipping does cause succeeded() to be false.

Comment: I used this, but when I click 'cancel' in the UI, the pipeline proceeds to the next stage and builds it.  Does clicking cancel on the pipeline stage trigger a different condition other than cancelled()?

Comment: Haven't experienced this behaviour @person0 . Cancelling the run should cause canceled() to be true and make the condition false.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for similar information, and found that you can do an "IN" clause on dependency result.  Found this in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) about expressions

```
- job: c
  dependsOn:
  - a
  - b
  condition: |
    and
    (
      in(dependencies.a.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped'),
      in(dependencies.b.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because the stage doesn't run that it doesn't get a status (eg succeeded, failed, canceled etc.). There is no status function for `skipped`.

With that, I think you will need to add a dependency on the stage before `Test` so that this evaluation can be made. Let's say that stage is called `Build`.

I think this condition should work: (line breaks are for readability only)

```
# run the stage if build is successful 
# and test succeeded or skipped 
# AND the branch is correct
and(
  and(succeeded('Build'), not(failed('Test'))), 
  in(variables['build.sourceBranchName'], 'master', 'DoUAT')
)
```

> **failed**
>
> - For a job:
>
>   - With no arguments, evaluates to True only if **any previous job** in the dependency graph failed.
>   - With job **names as arguments**, evaluates to **True only if** any of **those jobs failed**.

Because of this documentation, I think it's necessary to add the `Test` parameter to target that stage specifically. However, I'm not sure if this necessitates that the `Test` name be added to the `dependencies` section of the `UAT` stage.

Comment: Turns out this solution is more complicated than it needs to be.  The not(failed('Test')) is enough to achieve what I want. The implicit dependency on the preceding stage is enough to delay the UAT deployment until Test has been skipped.  Adding in explicit dependencies to all the preceding stages would get messy, as I actually have five stages--not just the two in my cut-down example.

Comment: I didn't think you would need to add explicit dependencies to all, just to `Test -1`, but if you're seeing that isn't necessary anyway, then great.